# Cos'è il "tono di testa"?

Tags: meaning

Nel libro autobiografico *Un grande avvenire dietro le spalle* di Vittorio Gassman ho letto:

> «Nino», disse il gran tragico, dopo una pausa interminabile, estraendo il suo famoso **tono di testa**, che l'inflessione toscana tinteggiava di disinvoltura, «Nino, che succede? La ragazza è addolorata, parla di piantarti.»

Non capisco cosa vuol dire "tono di testa" in questo brano. Ho cercato se c'era qualcosa al riguardo nelle voci "tono" e "testa" del vocabolario Treccani, ma non ho trovato nulla. Per questa ragione vi chiedo: sapreste spiegarmi qual è il significato di "tono di testa"?

**Aggiornamento:** "il gran tragico" in questo brano è l'attore Renzo Ricci, suocero in quel momento di Vittorio Gassman.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si riferisce al modo di impostare il registro vocale: "tono, timbro, o voce di testa" (di petto, di gola, ecc.).

Questo avviene sia nel [recitativo](http://www.dedalart.com/syllabus/voce.htm) (che è il caso che ci interessa qui) che nel canto:

> A seconda del modo in cui la voce viene prodotta si possono
>   distinguere diversi tipi di emissione: infatti tra la voce di petto e
>   quella di falsetto esistono varie emissioni intermedie che sfruttano
>   prevalentemente il registro di petto per i suoni gravi e quello di
>   testa per le note acute.
>                                      https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canto_(musica)

I diversi registri della voce, tra i quali quello di testa, si possono spiegare così (si parla di canto, ma è la stessa tecnica nel teatro):

> I registri della voce assumono denominazione diversa a seconda della parte del corpo che entra in risonanza durante il canto. La vibrazione delle corde vocali sarebbe inavvertibile senza un elemento che la facesse risuonare. Se risuona la cassa toracica o almeno il mediastino, in particolare durante l'esecuzione di note di frequenza bassa, la voce si dice in registro di petto; se risuona, per note maggiormente acute, solo nella gola, si dice in registro di gola (e viene evitata assolutamente durante il canto perché produce un suono debole, stridulo e poco gradevole); se risuona in testa sfruttandone le cavità (compresi i seni nasali e frontali), durante l'esecuzione di note molto acute, si dice in **registro di testa**.
>   https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tecnica_del_canto#I_registri_della_voce

Comment: Vedo che si trova informazione anche qui: https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tecnica_del_canto#I_registri_della_voce. Se vuoi, puoi integrarla alla tua risposta.

Comment: Veramente qui non si tratta di canto, ma di un attore (Renzo Ricci, suocero in quel momento di Vittorio Gassman) che probabilmente usava questa tecnica nel teatro.

Comment: Scusa, @Iserni, non sarebbe "recitazione teatrale" invece di "recitativo"?

Comment: Ho aggiunto l'informazione che appare nell'articolo di Wikipedia che ho menzionato prima. Penso che così si capisca meglio il significato di "tono di testa".

Comment: Non ne sono sicuro... credo che si applichi ad entrambe le modalità.

Comment: Hai fatto benissimo, grazie! :-)

Comment: Se cerchi i vocaboli nel Treccani, puoi vedere che "recitativo" è un modo di cantare. Si possono trovare "recitativi" nelle opere o negli oratori (composizioni musicali). Invece "recitazione" è l'azione, l’attività, l’arte e la tecnica, il modo stesso di recitare...